# find index of word from list of words in text file in python

Tags: python, trim

I have list of words in text file, and I have list of text files with reach text.

The list of words in text file has words that are starting word, like line containing below those words are considered .

same another text file has words that are starting word, like lines containing above those words are considered.

In short I want to trim my text files using those words.

Here is the code:

```
# Load the text file
Textfile=[]
lines=[]
path="Images for summarization _# CTScan/"
for text in sorted(os.listdir(path+'text/'),key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[0]):  
    Textfile.append(open(path+"text/"+text,'r').read().lower())
    lines.append(open(path+"text/"+text,'r').read().lower().splitlines())

## Trimming part
Trimed_words_top=open(path+"Words for Trimming above.txt",'r').read()
Trimed_words_below=open(path+"Words for Trimming below.txt",'r').read()
Trimed_words_top=Trimed_words_top.lower().splitlines()
Trimed_words_below=Trimed_words_below.lower().splitlines()
Word_index_top=[]
data=[]
Trimmed_text=[]
""" 
for line in lines:
    for word in Trimed_words_top:
        if word 
        data=lines[Word_index_top[0]+1:]
        Trimmed_text=' '.join(word for word in data) 
"""
# This is one for single file , need to do it for all

SinglesFile=lines[0]

Word_index_top=[i for i, s in enumerate(SinglesFile) if 'ncct' in s]

## here is the logic for word trimming
cnt=0
Word_index_top=[]
for line in lines:
            Word_index_top.append([i for i, s in enumerate(line) for word in Trimed_words_top if word in s])
            cnt+=1
```

Comment: You have a lot of code. Can you shorten it down to just the crux of it, with an [mvce]? Maybe a toy example.

Comment: And your problem is what exactly? A snippet of your data files wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @zwer I want to trim my text files using trim points(words in file) , I have words for trimming above and trimming below. for example , I have a text file which has word 'ncct' and my list of word has also ncct . so text will be trimmed and sentences above the line containing ncct will be removed and same for sentences below line will be removed

Comment: I edited the code , look for single file section . I need to do it for all the files .